# Where is this clip of Darth Vader from?

Tags: story-identification, star-wars, darth-vader

I want to know where this clip of Darth Vader turning around in slow motion is from. The clip I’m talking about is at the 1:53 and 2:10 mark.

Comment: A comment on the video says it's from a Vader fan film but I haven't been able to ID it yet.

Comment: @SpaceWolf1701 - The commenter is wrong, as youtube commenters so often are. I guess we should be thankful that they didn't finish their comment by insulting someone's mother and using the n-word

Comment: @Valorum Multiple comments, actually. But yes that would explain why I couldn't find it. Ah well.

Comment: @SpaceWolf1701 - Hence why you need to ask it here instead of on Youtube :-) We have many abilities that some consider to be ... *unnatural*.

Comment: @Valorum Unnatural abilities sound like *heresy* to me...

Comment: You can find out what the video is from. *But not from a Jedi*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The clip was taken from this trailer for the [Star Wars: Darth Vader VR Experience](https://io9.gizmodo.com/darth-vader-and-david-goyer-team-up-for-star-wars-next-1783801997).